# Script that Show which hdisks each of the filesystems reside on for IBM AIX

Tags: unix, ksh, aix

i have the folowing script that Show which hdisks each of the filesystems reside on for IBM AIX.

```
#!/bin/ksh
for vg in `lsvg -o`; do 
    for fs in `lsvgfs $vg`; do 
            printf "%-22s" $fs; 
            for disk in `lsvg -p $vg | tail +3 | awk '{print $1}'`; do
                    lspv -l $disk | grep -q " ${fs}$" && printf "%-8s" $disk; 
            done; 
            echo
    done; 
done
```

Here is what the output looks like:

```
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys1hdisk189hdisk200hdisk146hdisk151hdisk136hdisk141
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys2hdisk188hdisk201hdisk144hdisk152hdisk137hdisk191
```

first the output won't show up correctly as it should be like this:

```
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys1    hdisk189 hdisk200 hdisk146 hdisk151 hdisk136 hdisk141
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys2    hdisk188 hdisk201 hdisk144 hdisk152 hdisk137 hdisk191
```

and i need to upgrade it to see the total space of the disk and the used space by the file system in every one of them something like

```
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys1    hdisk189 hdisk200 hdisk146 hdisk151 hdisk136 hdisk141
                         1000g    2000g    1000g    1000g    3000g    1000g
                          300g     500g     250g      90g      80g      30g 

/apps/data/IAMV1/sys2    hdisk188 hdisk201 hdisk144 hdisk152 hdisk137 hdisk191
                         1000g    2000g    1000g    1000g    3000g    1000g
                          300g     500g     250g      90g      80g      30g
```

in this example the fs /apps/data/IAMV1/sys1 uses 300g from hdisk189 
and so on ... to be honest i don't know how to do that i know i can have the total space of the disk using this

```
getconf DISK_SIZE /dev/hdisk189
```

thanks Everyone.

Comment: For spaces you can do `printf "%-22s  " $fs` and `printf "%-8s " $disk`

Comment: I don't have an AIX system, can you use something like `df` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an initial version, which might suit for your need. Tested on AIX 7.1.

I don't have a vg with multiple PV so I not sure if the text will align right.

Possible BUG: I phrased the `lspv` output with `awk` to get / PP size / Total PP / Used PP / count, and I do not know if this vary over different AIX versions.

---

`deccnt` - control the decimal count, change as you see fit. With little adjustment it can be provided as argument on script execution.

If the longest disk name shorter than the total disk size number and total disk size number greater than 8 char, then you will see miss alignments like this:

```
/apps/data/IAMV1/sys1    hdisk189 hdisk200   hdisk146 hdisk151 hdisk136 hdisk141
                         1000g    200000000g 1000g    1000g    3000g    1000g
                          300g         5000g  250g      90g      80g      30g 

/apps/data/IAMV1/sys2    hdisk188 hdisk201 hdisk144 hdisk152     hdisk137 hdisk191
                         1000g    2000g    1000g    10000000000g 3000g    1000g
                          300g     500g     250g             90g   80g      30g
```

Issue can be mitigated further by increase the lower 8 char hard cap here `BEGIN{lng=0;cap=8}')`, but that will also increase the default spacing between the disks columns. I do not believe you will see this behavior often but I wanted to mention it. In any other case the alignment should be good.

```
#!/bin/ksh

# Accuracy
deccnt='2'

# FS name lenght 
fsLng=$(lsvg -l rootvg | awk 'BEGIN{lng=0} !/N\/A/{if(NR>2){if (lng < length($7)){lng=length($7)}}} END{print lng}')
# Disk name lenght | cant be less than 8 
diskLng=$(lspv | awk 'BEGIN{lng=0;cap=8} !/N\/A/{if(NR>2){if(lng < length($1)){lng=length($1)}}} END{if(lng > cap){print lng}else{print cap}}')

for vg in $(lsvg -o)
do
  for fs in $(lsvgfs ${vg})
  do
    line1="$(printf "%-${fsLng}s  " ${fs})"
    line2="$(printf "%-${fsLng}s  " '')"
    line3="$(printf "%-${fsLng}s  " '')"

    for disk in $(lsvg -p $vg | awk '{if(NR>2){print $1}} END{print "hdisk0";print "hdisk0"}')
    do
      set -A diskparam $(lspv ${disk} | awk 'BEGIN{PPsize=0;PPtotal=0;PPused=0}
        /^PP SIZE:/{ if($4~"gigabyte" ){PPsize=$3}else 
                     if($4~"megabyte" ){PPsize=$3/1000}else 
                     if($4~"kilobyte" ){PPsize=$3/1000000} }
        /^TOTAL PPs:/{ PPtotal=$3 }
        /^USED PPs:/{ PPused=$3 }
        END{ GBtotal=PPtotal*PPsize
             GBused=PPused*PPsize
             print length(int(GBtotal))" "GBtotal" "GBused
           }
      ')

      NumWdt=$(( ${diskparam[0]}+${deccnt} ))
      [[ ${deccnt} -ne  0 ]] && (( NumWdt=NumWdt+1 )) # +1 due we have decimal point char

      if [[ ${NumWdt} -lt ${diskLng} ]]
      then
        colWdt=${diskLng}
      else
        colWdt=$(( ${NumWdt}+1 )) # +1 hence 'g' char make line2-3 larger if NumWdt control the column width. 
      fi

      if lspv -l ${disk} | grep -q " ${fs}$"
      then
        line1="${line1} $(printf "%-${diskLng}s%-$(( ${colWdt}-${diskLng} ))s" ${disk} '')"
        line2="${line2} $(printf "%${NumWdt}.${deccnt}f%-$(( ${colWdt}-${NumWdt} ))s" ${diskparam[1]} 'g')"
        line3="${line3} $(printf "%${NumWdt}.${deccnt}f%-$(( ${colWdt}-${NumWdt} ))s" ${diskparam[2]} 'g')"
      fi
    done
    print "${line1}\n${line2}\n${line3}\n"
  done
  print
done
```

Comment: it works like a charm thanks, you were right about the improvement that should be made but still the results are on point. :)

Comment: Great, I updated my answer, now it handle the numbers and alignment better.

Comment: great i just added some spaces here

       line2="$(printf "             %-${fsLng}s  " '')"
       line3="$(printf "             %-${fsLng}s  " '')"

because the results show up under the file system, thanks a lot for your your help.